# Does release semantics in x86 only affects read and write instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86

A write instruction in x86 have release semantics, and this [tutorial](http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/) says the following about what release semantics mean:

> Release semantics prevent memory reordering of the write-release with
>   any read or write operation that precedes it in program order.

So if I have the following instructions:

```
read_instruction_1
read_instruction_2
write_instruction_1
write_instruction_2 (the above instructions will no be reordered to below this instruction)
read_instruction_3
write_instruction_3
```

The instructions above `write_instruction_2` will not be reordered to below  `write_instruction_2`.

---

But what if I have something like this:

```
read_instruction_1
read_instruction_2
write_instruction_1
a_non_read_or_write_instruction
write_instruction_2 (will a_non_read_or_write_instruction not be reordered to below this instruction?)
read_instruction_3
write_instruction_3
```

The `a_non_read_or_write_instruction` instruction is not a read or write instruction, but I don't want it to be reordered to below `write_instruction_2`, will it not be reordered to below `write_instruction_2`?

Comment: Since it's not a read or write, you can't tell the difference. Thus the processor is allowed to reorder it, unless you use a serializing instruction.

Comment: On Intel CPUs (but not AMD), `lfence` is an *execution* barrier (see [Are loads and stores the only instructions that gets reordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50494658)) so you could use that as a lighter-weight alternative to a full serializing instruction.  Are you creating a microbenchmark or something?  Otherwise I can't see why you'd need to stop the CPU from running faster.

Comment: @Peter Cordes *"I can't see why you'd need to stop the CPU from running faster"* `write_instruction_2` is setting a flag that will be read by another thread, and when the other thread reads this flag, it should assume that all instructions above `write_instruction_2` have been executed.

Comment: @user8426277: If `a_non_read_or_write_instruction` is an input to `write_instruction_2`, then `write_instruction_2` already has to wait for it as an input dependency.  If not, then no other thread cares whether some independent register-register local operation in another thread happens before or after the stores execute, or become globally visible (which is a separate thing because of the store buffer).