# Does it matter if the non read and non write instructions are reordered in x86?

Tags: multithreading, assembly, x86, memory-barriers

The `mfence` [documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MFENCE.html) says the following:

> Performs a serializing operation on all load-from-memory and
>   store-to-memory instructions that were issued prior the MFENCE
>   instruction. This serializing operation guarantees that every load and
>   store instruction that precedes the MFENCE instruction in program
>   order becomes globally visible before any load or store instruction
>   that follows the MFENCE instruction.

As far as I know, there is no fence instruction in x86 that prevents the reordering of non read and non write instructions.

Now if my program only have one thread, even if the instructions are reordered, it would still seem as if the instructions are executing in order.

But what if my program have multiple threads, and in one of the threads the non read and non write instructions are reordered, will the other threads notice this reordering (I assume the answer is **No**, or else there would be a fence instruction to stop the non read and non write instructions reordering, or maybe I'm missing something)?

Comment: How would another thread detect a reordering of a non-memory operation?

Comment: @RaymondChen: If one of those instructions is `rdtsc`, then the difference becomes architecturally-visible as a value in a register.  But that's a very specific case.  Fun fact: on Skylake at least, `mfence` in practice does prevent reordering of *all* instructions, like `lfence`.  [Are loads and stores the only instructions that gets reordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50496379).  This is an implementation detail though; on paper it only blocks reordering of memory instructions. (But it's part of why the Linux kernel for example has reverted to `lock or [rsp], 0` instead of MFENCE)

Answer (score 5):

> will the other threads notice this reordering

No, other than performance (timing or direct measurement with HW performance counters).  Or microarchitectural side-channels (like ALU port pressure for logical cores that share a physical core with Hyperthreading / SMT): one thread can time *itself* to learn something about what the other hardware thread is executing.

The only "normal" way for threads to observe anything about each other is by loading data that other threads stored.

Even load ordering is only visible indirectly (by the effect it has on what the other thread decides to later store).

---

> As far as I know, there is no fence instruction in x86 that prevents the reordering of non read and non write instructions.

**On Intel CPUs (but not AMD), `lfence` does this**.  Intel's manual says so, this is *not* just an implementation detail.  It's actually guaranteed for future microarchitectures.

> Intel's [LFENCE instruction-set reference manual entry](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/LFENCE.html):
>
> LFENCE does not execute until **all** prior instructions have completed locally, and **no later instruction** begins execution until LFENCE completes.

(completed locally = retired from the out-of-order core, i.e. leaves the ROB).

`lfence` is not particularly useful as an actual load barrier, because x86 doesn't allow weakly-ordered loads from WB memory (only from WC).  (Not even `movntdqa` or `prefetchnta` can create weakly-ordered loads from normal WB memory.)  So unlike `sfence`, `lfence` is basically never needed for memory ordering, *only* for its special effects, like  `lfence` ; `rdtsc`.  Or for Spectre mitigation, to block speculative execution past it.

---

But as an implementation detail, on Intel CPUs including at least Skylake, `mfence` *is* a barrier for out-of-order execution.  **See [Are loads and stores the only instructions that gets reordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494658/are-loads-and-stores-the-only-instructions-that-gets-reordered/50496379#50496379) for that, and much more related stuff.**