# Are there any processors vulnerabilities other than Meltdown and Spectre?

Tags: security, hardware, cpu-architecture, microprocessors

I read about the two vulnerabilities and also read about the CPU and processors' history a bit. I want to know if there are anymore of the hardware (especially those of the processors) before.

Comment: *Off-topic* on StackOverflow. In general, **processors have bugs too** (e.g. the old [Pentium FDIV bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug)...). Their specification is an [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)). That fact was noticed as early as the 1940s by Von Neumann, and probably was one of the roots of computer science

Comment: I encountered a hardware bug as early as 1983. On [ND-500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ND-500). My father and my masters (e.g. J.Pitrat) had hardware bugs on IBM7094. In the 1960s computers were less reliable than today.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: A more security-relevant example is the [Pentium `F00F` bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_F00F_bug), where `lock cmpxchg8b eax` (with a register, not memory, operand) locks the CPU until a hard reboot, giving a DOS attack from unprivileged userspace.   It's basically a halt-and-catch-fire instruction, but apparently it could be worked around in software.

Comment: Any hardware bug where the actual computer don't operate as specified can be relevant to security (especially if you can reproduce that bug)

Comment: So, it's meaning that every processors' architectures are likely to have bugs which can be related to the security issues. People don't notice them because of abstraction.

Comment: Not exactly "are likely to have bugs" but just "could have bugs". Notice that you never program a *real* computer, but only the *abstraction* written in its specification. If you buy a laptop, what exactly happens when you smash it on the floor is not specified, but your laptop is then broken, and probably cannot run software anymore. But the laptop is not supposed to be dropt on the floor while running! If you really want a laptop capable of being dropt, buy some other machine (much more expensive).

Comment: Indeed the x86 specification is so complex (it is documented in many thousands of pages, downloadable from many sites, including Intel's and AMD's) that hardware vendors still make bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All CPU designs have at least some subtle design flaws.  We call these "errata".

There have been some security-relevant CPU bugs.  Usually "just" DOS attacks, though.

The [Pentium `F00F` bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_F00F_bug) affected all Intel P5 microarchitectures before the B2 stepping (which fixed it).  The `lock cmpxchg8b eax` (with a register operand, not memory, thus invalid) locks the CPU until a hard reboot, giving a DOS attack from unprivileged userspace.  (Wikipedia says it fetched the illegal-instruction IDT entry using a `lock`ed bus cycle, so the system stayed locked waiting for the corresponding write that never came).   It could be worked around in software by forcing the CPU to page-fault while trying to handle the exception.

That wikipedia entry compares it to the [Cyrix "coma bug"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrix_coma_bug), on Cyrix CPUs from a similar era.

---

Intel's design and verification techniques have advanced since then: CPUs after Pentium have updateable microcode, and they simulate a gate-level software model of the CPU by throwing randomized instruction sequences at it, to catch unexpected behaviour even in weird microarchitectural states.

But bugs can still happen.  Skylake needed a microcode update to disable its loop buffer after it turned out that [AH-merging uops weren't always handled correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to) with hyperthreading enabled, leading to unexpected crashes when running code generated by the OCaml compiler (erratum SKL150).  (My understanding is that Coffee Lake has a working loop buffer, but SKL and KBL only run from the uop cache even for tight loops.)  I think this would at best be a lockup bug; too hard to get anything specific to happen to read secrets or gain privileges.

Similarly, Skylake's `mfence` was made extra strong in a microcode update (blocking out-of-order execution entirely, like `lfence`) [to fix erratum SKL079](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494658/are-loads-and-stores-the-only-instructions-that-gets-reordered/50496379#50496379).  Probably you can't exploit reordering of `movntdqa` weakly-ordered loads from WC memory (e.g. video RAM), but it's at least possible the security / correctness of something could depend on it.

See https://www3.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/desktop-6th-gen-core-family-spec-update.pdf for a complete list of Skylake errata.

AMD of course publishes errata for their CPUs, too.

---

**What's different about Meltdown and Spectre is that CPU architects knew CPUs worked that way**, but didn't realize there was a way to exploit it.  It's pretty subtle, turning secret data into microarchitectural state, then reading that microarchitectural state back into *architectural* state (actual values in registers on the correct path, not in the shadow of a mispredict).

For all we know, there are other nasty surprises (new classes of microarchitectural attacks) that we'll need to redesign CPUs to efficiently mitigate.

(Meltdown is very easy to cheaply mitigate with a new design, just mask under-privileged TLB+L1d hits to 0 instead of returning the actual data.  This is what some CPUs already do, according to this [StuffedCow blog article](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/05/meltdown-microarchitecture/) that tested many microarches.  Spectre is very hard to do *cheaply*, though.)

Hyperthreading (and in general any SMT) already exposes microarchitectural timing side-channels between threads sharing a physical core.  For this and other reasons, crypto algorithms are often written carefully so their performance is not data dependent.  This means avoiding lookup tables that can miss in cache.  Timing side-channels are a known attack, though.